# HashMap with camel cxf:component POJO dataFormat

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, cxf, apache-camel

my WS-Interface:

```
@WebService
public interface WS{

    String decide(String word, MapWrapper parameters);

}
```

with WrapperClass:

```
public class MapWrapper {

    public HashMap<String, String> map;
}
```

and

```
from("cxf:http://localhost:8080/WS?serviceClass=ws.WS&dataFormat=POJO").to("stream:out"); //Just for testing purpose
```

gives following exception when invoked with SOAPUI:

```
Error during type conversion from type: org.apache.cxf.message.MessageContentsList to the required type: byte[] with value [Test, ws.WS@1221bc6] due argument type mismatch
```

I think the MapWrapper class caused this exception. But how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same issue over and over....

Do **NOT** use `Java` specific constructs in your interfaces you expose as Web Services. I am taking about the `HashMap`.

Web Services are an integration technology meant to connect components in any platform (even non-OO clients). All the objects passed in web services should be value transfer objects. Not complex bussiness objects etc.

Not only this is the correct approach, it is the approach with the least problems during coding and deploying.

Comment: ok. But needing a HashMap or at least something similar, what would work?

Comment: I suggest you redesign your interface.If this is not possible then you could "simulate" the hashmap via array of arrays.I.e. use an array of rows where each row is an array of 2 elements, the key and the value

Comment: I understand your point that WebServices should be platform independent. But in my case, the WS is just a embedded interface, the java application can be called with.